# Record, save & play saved sound files on a web page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, audio, web

I plan to create a page that can record a sound from your computer's microphone and save the sound file to a server/host (supposedly?). And from the same page, you can play all saved sound files on the server simultaneously (a better choice would be the files start at different times: +/- 3 secs).

Example: A, B, C all recorded their hands clappings on different days. D just visited the page and wants to know what's the current state of all sound files now, so he hits the play button and the page plays A, B & C's hands clappings all together. D thinks he wants to join in, so he's going to record his hands clapping, too.

So far, I've found some jQuery libraries that can do a similar task (closest: http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder/), but none can play all previously recorded sound files from where they're saved.

Is there anyway to make it happen?

Comment: so your question boids down to "How can I play more than one sound at the same time"? Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Kinda. The tricky part is those sound files are added on the client's side. So the number of files will keep increasing.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Recorder.js from Matt Diamond https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs